# How to debug Flutter app on an external Windows 10 IoT device?

Tags: flutter, windows, flutter-windows

I'm developing a Flutter app for Windows. The app will be used in kiosk mode on a computer that runs Windows 10 IoT Enterprise. Is there a way to connect that computer to a developers computer and debug Flutter app on it?

I tried to connect via an USB cable, but the computer doesn't get recognized as I expected because my computer and the target computer are both master devices.